# Eclipse dont mark correctly occurrences

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I don't know why Eclipse incorrectly mark occurrences of, for example, variables in my code. This is a screenshoot:

[image]

What is Eclipse selecting ???? And, If I put the cursor on any part without any varible, it show a lot of highlight over the screen:

[image]

Any idea ? Thanks!

Comment: What language and editor is this?  It makes a difference.  But this just looks like a bug you need to report.

Comment: Editor is Eclipse (as stated) and language is PHP. Dont think it's a bug, because in some other files, highlight works ok.

Comment: Sure it is a bug.. It happens to me a lot. It is serious as I am about stop using it.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me in JDT (Java code) every once in a while. Try working through these steps (in increasing order of severity) until the problem goes away:

1. Clean the project or the entire workspace (Project -> Clean...)
2. Close the editor tab for that file (File -> Close, or Ctrl-W), then open it again
3. Right click the PDT project in the explorer and close the project (this should have the side effect of closing all the editor tabs associated with that PDT project), then open the project again
4. Close the project (like in step 3) but quit Eclipse and then restart it before opening the project again

Usually step 1 or 2 will fix the problem, but there are times when I have had to go all the way to step 4 to get JDT to behave itself.

Comment: Thanks, but except step 1, i've already done all other. Project->Clean... is grayed for me.

Comment: Then it probably is a bug related to the specific contents of that php file. You could verify: send the file (or whole project, minus eclipse config files) to another computer and see if you get the same problem with Mark Occurrences there.

Answer (score 0):

This was the main reason I switched to NetBeans for PHP development, once I have modified the source code I have to close and re-open it in order for mark occurence working properly, so boring. only happens in PHP editor, for Java editor, all fine